# Caching issues in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching, dotnetnuke

I have been scratching my head for this from last one week, i will really appreciate any help here, so here we go:

I have a website running on Dnn 7.4 and i want to add caching functionality on it. On first attempt it reads from database and on second attempt onwards it should read from cache, the problem is on first attempt it reads as expected, on 2nd attempt it reads from cache also, but then again on 3rd attempt it fetches from database. Here's my simple code:

```
if (Cache["Something"] != null)
{
    Response.Write("Cache" + Cache["Something"]);
}
else
{
    Cache["Something"] = "Cool";
    Response.Write("Latest" + Cache["Something"]);
}
```

DataCache implementation:

```
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;

string dCache = DataCache.GetCache("test") as string;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dCache))
{
    DataCache.SetCache("test", "cache content");
    Response.Write("From Database: cache content");
}
else
{
    Response.Write("From Cache: " + dCache);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not show what kind of cache you are using and your policies of the cached items. Here a sample on how it might work with a MemoryCache:

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
string something = cache["Something"] as string;
if (something == null){
    CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    //Configure your expire policy here
    cache.Set("Something", "Cool", policy);
    something = "Cool";
}
return something;
```

Now you only have to configure the policy for the cache item handling.

Comment: Hi @Peter i just want to use simple cache object to store my data from database, and this i have been using with multiple projects, not sure why it's not working here.

Comment: You probably using a local variable as càche object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use DataCache from DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities

```
//Get Cache
string str = DataCache.GetCache("something") as string;

//Remove cache
DataCache.RemoveCache("something");

// Set Cache
DataCache.SetCache("something", "value of something");
```

Comment: Hi @erw13n : i tried DataCache as well, it works if i continuously hit the page as soon as i keep it idle even for a minute and access the page it could not get the cache object, i don't know what's wrong haven't ever came across such issue before i have updated my question with the code of DataCache i am using. Does this requires any IIS configuration, i am currently on shared server, does that makes any difference?